# Node.js Cannot find package imported from

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have a problem with deploying my project onto server, on my pc everything works fine and there is no imports problems. Thank you for ur help!

**Error Message:**

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/home/igor/backend/alina_edu/router/articleRoutes.js' imported from /home/igor/backend/alina_edu/index.js
    at new NodeError (internal/errors.js:322:7)
    at finalizeResolution (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:318:11)
    at moduleResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:776:10)
    at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:887:11)
    at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:89:40)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:242:28)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:76:40)
    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:75:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

**Imports from index.js:**

```
import courseRoutes from "./router/CourseRoutes.js";
import authRoutes from './router/authRoutes.js';
import articleRoutes from './router/articleRoutes.js';
import tagsRouter from "./router/TagsRouter.js";
import testsRoutes from "./router/TestsRoutes.js";
```

**Package.json module annotation**

```
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
```

**ArticleRoutes.js itself**

```
import {Router} from "express";
import ArticleController from "../controllers/ArticleController.js";
const articleRoutes = new Router();

// ...blah-blah-blah...

export default articleRoutes;
```

**Server settings:**

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Node.js v16.16.0
- NPM v8.16.0

Comment: Have you installed the dependencies `npm install`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox yep, i think problem is not about node_modules

Comment: can you check if node_modules is getting installed in root of project ? also was there any error installing any package ?

Comment: All modules are installed correctly via npm install

Answer (score 0):

Are you developing on a Windows machine and deploying to an Ubuntu machine?

## CAPS

Your files have capital letters in them (e.g. `CourseRoutes.js`), which Windows ignores. Filenames in Windows are case-insensitive, but case-sensitive in Ubuntu, so if the upper/lowercase, it will work on Windows but fail in Ubuntu.

### verification

If you're using source control, check the case of the filenames in the web interface (e.g. GitHub) or by cloning a new repo. If you aren't using source control, use source control.